# DC.js Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'by') at _chart.ordering

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I'm running DC.js rev 3.0.2 and D3.js rev 5.16.0 and Crossfilter.js rev 1.5.4. When creating a simple pie chart from the [examples](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/), it doesn't show anything and gives the following output in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'by')` 
at _chart.ordering (base-mixin.js:348:44)
at dc.capMixin (cap-mixin.js:20:12)  
at dc.pieChart (pie-chart.js:47:21)
at pie.html:19:16
```

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var chart = dc.pieChart("#test");
d3.csv("morley.csv").then(function(experiments) {
    var ndx           = crossfilter(experiments),
    runDimension  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return "run-"+d.Run;})
    speedSumGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.Speed * d.Run;});

    chart
        .width(768)
        .height(480)
        .slicesCap(4)
        .innerRadius(100)
        .dimension(runDimension)
        .group(speedSumGroup)
        .legend(dc.legend().highlightSelected(true))
        // workaround for #703: not enough data is accessible through .label() to display percentages
        .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
            chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
                return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
            })
        });
    chart.render();
});
```

The piechart is working in Chrome but not in Edge, Firefox or on my Android mobile.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite JavaScript forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Please post a sample of your `morley.csv` file. It doesn't have to have identical data (if you're not comfortable with sharing it, or if it's too large), but we need to know something about the data you're using with your `d3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dc.js 3.0.2 is an old version (from 2018).

If you’re using an old version and run into these kinds of problems, you should check the `package.json` to see if you are using compatible versions of dependent libraries.

In this case, it says you should use crossfilter 1.4.5, which still supports sorting functions.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/3.0.2/package.json#L28